# Tornado login form unit test

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following Tornado 6.0.3 Web server:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import json

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

    def set_current_user(self, user):
        print('setting secure cookie', user)
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", user)  

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

        def get(self):
                self.render('login.html')

        def post(self):
            user = self.get_argument("user")
            self.set_current_user(user)
            self.redirect("/")

class IndexHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = self.get_current_user()
        print('getting current user in IndexHandler', self.get_current_user()) 
        if user:
            self.write('Hi, ' + user.decode('utf-8')) 
        else:
            self.write("Hi, unknown. <a href='/login'>Login</a>")              

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("user")


def make_app():   
    settings = {
            "cookie_secret":"61oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/Vo=",
            "login_url":"/login",
            "debug":False,
            'xsrf_cookies': True,
            }
    return tornado.web.Application([
            (r"/", IndexHandler),
            (r"/login", LoginHandler),
            (r"/logout", LogoutHandler),            
            ], **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = make_app()
    application.listen(8005)
    print('sample_app server started')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

login.html is defined this way:

```
<form method='POST'>
    user <input type='text' name='user' id='user'><br>
    password <input type='text' name='password' id='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Valider'>
    {% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
</form>
```

This application works correctly. When I go to the login page and type 'bla' for user and 'bla bla' for password, I get: 'Hi, bla' in the browser, and the trace is:

```
sample_app server started
getting current user in IndexHandler None
setting secure cookie bla
getting current user in IndexHandler b'bla'
```

Now, when I write the following test:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from sample_app import *
from urllib.parse import urlencode


class AppTestCase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        self.app = make_app()
        return self.app

    def test_login(self):
        p = {'user': 'bla', 'password': 'bla bla', '_xsrf': "dummy"}
        response = self.fetch('/login', method='POST', body=urlencode(p), headers={"Cookie": "_xsrf=dummy"})
        print("\n", response.body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I get for `response`: Hi, unknown. Login,
and the trace is:

```
setting secure cookie bla
getting current user in IndexHandler None
```

Why secure cookie is not correctly set in test mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Tornado's default HTTP client doesn't support cookies (secure or not). You can set `follow_redirects=False` and see that the `Set-Cookie` header is set on the response from `/login`, but there's not currently a way to pass that cookie to the index handler automatically with the default client.

If you use the curl HTTP client instead, I think you can configure this to process cookies, but I haven't tried this myself and don't know how to configure it to do this.

Comment: Well, you are a Tornado guru, and if you have no direct answer, I guess that I have taken the wrong way. Tornado has a `tornado.testing` module, so I can imagine that the designers of Tornado have thought to the following question: "how should a form with an xsrf cookie set by Tornado should be unit tested ?". I read through the doc, and looked at other SO questions, but could not find an answer to this question.